# What is the origin of fans chanting players' names with an extended "u" sound?

Tags: history, fans

At many American sporting events, if a player with a "u" sound in his name is on the home team, and he enters the game or makes a play in the game, then there is a good chance the fans will chant his name with an extended "u" sound.

Here are a few examples:

- Whenever fullback [John Kuhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kuhn) of the Green Bay Packers touches the ball at a home game, then the fans will chant "Kuuuuuuuuuhn".
- In the 1990s, [Daryl Johnston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daryl_Johnston) was a fullback with the Dallas Cowboys.  His nickname was "Moose".  Whenever he touched the ball at a home game, the fans would chant "Moooooooose".
- [Luke Walton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Walton) was a basketball player for the L.A. Lakers, and whenever he entered a game at home, the fans would chant "Luuuuuuuuke".
- In the 1980s, [Joe Dumars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Dumars) was a basketball player for the Detroit Pistons, and whenever he scored a basket at a home game, the P.A. announcer would yell "Joe Duuuuuuuuumars!"

When did this tradition originate?

Comment: Another example is Ruud van Nistelrooy of United, where the fans would scream "Ruuuuuud" after he scores, which confused some people since it sounds like they are booing him :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sHcp3-ka3M

Comment: It dates at least back to the 60s, as [Ron Luciano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Luciano) mentions it in his books.

Comment: I don't have an answer for where it first started, but those long vowel sounds lend themselves to that type of call, and coupled with the fact that there's some irony in it sounding like booing when it's not, I wouldn't be surprised if it "originated" in a few different places.

Comment: Another example is Roberto Luongo of the National Hockey League. When he used to play for the Vancouver Canucks they would chant `Luuuuuuuuuuuu` after any significant save, although I am not sure if the Florida Panthers fans have kept up the tradition.

Comment: It's a vowel sound. You can stretch vowel sounds more easily than consonants. I think it's the idea of stretching out names in general. You just happened to pick a bunch of examples with an 'ooooo' sound. I recall other names being stretched out without 'ooo' sounds such as "Darrrrrrrrr-illllllll [Darryl Strawberry]"

Comment: This same treatment is given to Panthers Linebacker Luke Kuechly.

Answer (score -1):

Boog Powell played first base for the Baltimore Orioles from 1961 until 1974. I recall watching baseball on color TV (which was fairly new technology) and seeing Powell play for Baltimore against other American League teams. The Baltimore fans would chant, "Boooooog," when he did anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).